# Implementing url schema for mvc4 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am facing problem in url routing of the mvc4 project

i have developed a one to one message chat for user in the website and the url is

```
http://localhost:56275/Message?recieverUsersId=0
```

now what happen if someone open  recieverUsersId=1 it shows all the message of userid=1

what i want that this url should be like this

```
http://localhost:56275/Message
```

or userid should be in encrypted form

Comment: So you just don't want the user id to be in the URL?  I presume you want to do this so one user can't hijack another user's chat simply by changing the URL?

Comment: @asymptoticFault ya but i dont want that userid in the url it can be or not?

Comment: In order to keep the user id out of the URL you will either need to pass it to the server another way, possibly a form POST (though according to the HTTP this would not be an appropriate use of the verb), OR you need to already have the information available on the server.  Are the users authenticated?  If they are not, how are the ids assigned?  In this scenario I believe the latter of the two options is absolutely preferable because it is a security issue which is much more easily managed on the server.  The user is associated with a session and the information should be held there.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to really answer the question in full.  If I am user 1, why would this key need to be on the client at all?  If the key is the value I get to look at, then passing the value (valid or not ) should be completely acceptable, the backend should determine if I have access to the key.

Answer (score 1):

Just moving the ID from a `get` query string to a `post` body is not going to stop people reading other's chat messages.

If you are passing back the user ID then it will need to be encrypted (1 way) in which case you can then compare and use.

If you don't need or want to encrypt the user ID for client side use then ...

Depending on your authentication scheme, in your controller you can either cast from `User` to the appropriate `Identity` type or make sure you store the current users ID in session upon login and then read it from there. Once you have the user ID then you can pass it to your DAL/Repository/Service/... to get chat messages for this particular user.

You could then have a `route` like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "MyMessageRoute",
  "Message",
  new { controller = "ctrlName", action = "MyMessages" }
);
```

With a corresponding `Action` called `MyMessages()` which checks the user ID.

Comment: It does not need to be 2 way encrypted, and probably shouldn't be.  A Seeded Hash would be exponentially more secure.

Comment: i got this message after implementing above route method

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'recieverUsersId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int64)' in 'abc.Controllers.CommunicationController.MessageController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: http://localhost:56275/UserInfo/Index/2

facing same problem here if i change 1...2...3 than user are getting change

Comment: @NeerajMehta - you shouldn't need to have an int in your action - the idea is that you determine the user ID from server side or based on auth cookie. Remove your param from your action and you won't get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Never trust user input. You have to rely on your authentication & authorization mechanisms for this. ASP.NET MVC has many implementations in the template. Just use one of them or extend it to your own need. Then you can get the user id from `User` property inside any action method. You can take a look at these [Pluralsight videos](http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m7-security&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building) to see how you can use it in your application.

Comment: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/URLRequestSecurity

i have found this link for encrypting the url , is this useful or not?

Comment: Don't pass this information in URL. Use forms authentication. You are going to show the messages to the user if they belong to him.